# Plotting multiple lines in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm pretty new to R so I don't really know what I'm doing. Anyway, I have data in this format in excel (as a csv file):

```
dt <- data.frame(species = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4),
                 cover = rep(1:3, times = 4),
                 depth = rep(c(15, 30, 60, 90), times = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to plot a graph of cover against depth, with a different coloured line for each species, and a key for which species is which colour. I don't even know where to start.

Sorry if something similar has been asked before. Any help would be much appreciated!

Don't know if this is in a helpful format but here's some of the actual data, I need to read more about dput I think:

```
structure(list(species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L), .Label = c("Agaricia fragilis", "bryozoan", "Dichocoenia stokesi", 
"Diploria labyrinthiformis", "Diploria strigosa", "Madracis decactis", 
"Manicina", "Montastrea cavernosa", "Orbicella franksi", "Porites asteroides", 
"Siderastrea radians"), class = "factor"), cover = c(0.021212121, 
0.04047619, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.266666667, 4.269047619, 3.587878788, 
3.25, 0.118181818, 0.152380952, 0, 0.007142857, 3.806060606, 
2.983333333, 14.13030303, 15.76190476, 0.415151515, 0.2, 0.26969697, 
0.135714286), depth = c(30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 
30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 15L, 30L, 
15L)), .Names = c("species", "cover", "depth"), row.names = c(NA, 
22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It would be great if you can post an example of your dataset, not an image of the screenshot, which will make helps much easier.

Comment: Not entirely sure wht you mean, heres what some of it looks like: species        cover depth
1          Agaricia fragilis  0.021212121    30
2          Agaricia fragilis  0.040476190    15
3                   bryozoan  0.000000000    30
4                   bryozoan  0.000000000    15
5        Dichocoenia stokesi  0.000000000    30
6        Dichocoenia stokesi  0.000000000    15
7  Diploria labyrinthiformis  1.266666667    30
8  Diploria labyrinthiformis  4.269047619    15
9          Diploria strigosa  3.587878788    30
10         Diploria strigosa  3.250000000    15

Comment: Please do not post the updated information by comments. Updated the original post and use the `dput` function.

Comment: See this post to learn more about how to post a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example),

Comment: I have posted an answer based on your original example dataset. Notice that I used R code to create the example data frame based on the information from your image. If you can use this kind of code to make your example dataset reproducible, it would be easier for others to help. Image of screenshot is bad to share data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `ggplot2` package.

```
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)

# Create example data frame based on the original example the OP provided
dt <- data.frame(species = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 4),
                 cover = rep(1:3, times = 4),
                 depth = rep(c(15, 30, 60, 90), times = 3),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Plot the data
ggplot(dt, aes(x = depth, y = cover, group = species, colour = species)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's perfect! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going!

```
  df1 <- read.csv("//file_location.csv", headers=T)
  library(dplyr)
  df1 <- df1 %>% select(species, depth) %>% group_by(species) %>%
  summarise(mean(depth)
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(df1, aes(x=depth, y=species, group=species, color=species) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks. Though R is prompting me for something else after the third line.

Comment: The OP mentioned about plotting a graph of cover against depth. Although it is not completely clear to me what plots the OP wants, your `ggplot2` did not include any information about `cover`, so I guessed this answer may not be valid.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well I want a graph with depth on the x axis and cover on the y axis. Then I want a line for each species showing it's cover (percentage of surface area covered by that species) at each depth. Is that clearer?

Comment: `summarise(mean(depth)` there is a missing `)`